# Unique xml node

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I have a  simple xml as below, I have to extract the unique rows of p-node

```
<T1>
   <S1>
      <p1>0</p1>
      <p2>0</p2>
      <p3>0</p3>
      <p4>0</p4>
      <p5>0</p5>
      <p6>0</p6>
   </S1>
   <S1>
      <p1>0</p1>
      <p2>0</p2>
      <p3>0</p3>
      <p4>0</p4>
      <p5>0</p5>
      <p6>0</p6>
   </S1>
   <S1>
      <p6>0</p6>
      <p7>0</p7>
      <p8>0</p8>
      <p9>0</p9>
      <p10>0</p10>
   </S1>
   <S1>
      <p6>0</p6>
      <p7>0</p7>
      <p8>0</p8>
      <p9>0</p9>
      <p10>0</p10>
   </S1>
   <S1>
      <p11>0</p11>
      <p12>0</p12>
      <p13>0</p13>
      <p14>0</p14>
      <p15>0</p15>
      <p16>0</p16>
   </S1>
</T1>
```

I want all the unique node P.
I want output like

```
P1
P2
P3
P4
P5
P6
P7
P8
P9
p10
P11
P12
P13
P14
P15
P16
```

nodes in output using xslt.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a grouping question, and in XSLT 1.0 it would be solved using the [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not show any effort whatsoever, and you do not show any code you might have attempted already. However, I am feeling generous today, use the stylesheet below.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

As suggested by Michael already, use Muenchian grouping to identify unique nodes. Define a key that finds unique element names and apply templates only to those nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="elem-name" match="S1/*" use="name()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/T1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="S1/*[generate-id() =
        generate-id(key('elem-name', name())[1])]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'p')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:if test="following::*[starts-with(name(),'p')]">
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

If the `p` elements was only an example, you can also define a template match for

```
<xsl:template match="S1/*">
```

**Text Output**

```
p1
p2
p3
p4
p5
p6
p7
p8
p9
p10
p11
p12
p13
p14
p15
p16
```